# DB4Free: Cant connect to Database

Tags: php, mysql

Do you maybe know, what's wrong with my PHP code?

I can't connect to my database:

```
$db_link = mysqli_connect (db4free.net,user,pass,database);
```

Could it be, that the host is wrong?

I´m just getting this error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$db_link' (T_VARIABLE) in /users/dbase/www/index.php on line 10
```

Full code (https://ghostbin.com/paste/u4sza):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
​
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SQL ABFRAGE</title>
  </head>
    <body>
<?php
​
$db_link = mysqli_connect ('db4free.net:3306',user,pass,database); //Hier SQL Server Anmeldedaten eintragen!
$sql = 'select * from kunden;'; //HIER SQL ABFRAGE
​

​
$db_erg = mysqli_query( $db_link, $sql );
​
if ( ! $db_erg ){
    die('Ung&uuml;ltige Abfrage: ' . mysqli_error());//Hier werden Error Meldungen definiert
}
​
echo '<table border="1">'; //Es wird eine Tabelle erstellt
​
while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array( $db_erg, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ //für jeden Datensatz wird folgendes ausgegeben
​
  echo "<tr>";
​
  echo "<td>". $zeile['kunr'] . "</td>"; //HIER Tabellenspalte zuweisen!
​
  echo "<td>". $zeile['kuname'] . "</td>"; //HIER Tabellenspalte zuweisen!
​
  echo "<td>". $zeile['kuvorna'] . "</td>"; //HIER Tabellenspalte zuweisen!
​
  echo "<td>". $zeile['kustras'] . "</td>"; //HIER Tabellenspalte zuweisen!
​
  echo "<td>". $zeile['kuplz'] . "</td>"; //... Je nach dem, wie viele Spalten du hast.
​
  echo "<td>". $zeile['kuort'] . "</td>"; //...
​
  echo "</tr>";
​
}
​
echo "</table>"; //Ende der Tabelle
mysqli_free_result( $db_erg ); //SQL Werte werden aus dem Arbeitsspeicher gelöscht
?>
​
​
    </body>
​
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> put it in quotes like this

```
mysqli_connect('db4free.net',user,pass,database)
```

Comment: same.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$db_link' (T_VARIABLE) in /users/dbase/www/index.php on line 10

Comment: I don't think you need the port (as it's standard) and if you want to add it it should be after db_name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is caused by some non-ASCII characters in your code. If you run a hex dump on the code, you will see that almost every single blank line in your code begins with the octets `e2 80 8b`.

For example, lines 9-10 begin with:

```
e2 80 8b 0d 0a 24 64 62 5f 6c 69 6e 6b 20 3d 20  .....$db_link =
```

The `e2 80 8b` is the UTF-8 encoding of [`U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE`](http://codepoints.net/U+200B). If you remove the blank lines and re-type them, the code should work fine<sup>1</sup>.

Make sure you use a **text editor**, and not a word processor when you write and edit your source code.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You should of course check if the [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) call was successful before making further use of `$db_link`, and use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when outputting data from the database.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

try to remove the last quote form this line

```
$sql = 'select * from kunden;';
```

and make it

```
 $sql = 'select * from kunden';
```

i prefer to **copy and paste**

Comment: You removed a semicolon, not a quote. This wouldn't cause a syntax error in PHP anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still doesnt work. I´m pretty sure it is because of the hoster... I think the hostername is something else and I cant find it..

Comment: @MistBase try to do it on **wamp** server and replace the hoster with the default localhost if its worked then the error from your online hoster